# Powershell and Regex to Tidy generated SQL Script

Tags: sql, regex, powershell, replace

I'm using SQL package to generate a update script.

However I wanted to modify it to remove the comments and commands such as

```
:setvar DefaultDataPath ""
:setvar DefaultLogPath ""
```

I've tried a couple of goes at writing a powershell script to do this using a regular expression but can't seem to get it working.

**SQL Script Extract**

```
/*
Deployment script for Genohsis/p:AllowIncompatiblePlatform=True/p:CommentOutSetVarDeclarations=True

This code was generated by a tool.
Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
the code is regenerated.
*/

GO
SET ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;

SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF;


GO
:setvar DatabaseName "Genohsis/p:AllowIncompatiblePlatform=True/p:CommentOutSetVarDeclarations=True"
:setvar DefaultFilePrefix "Genohsis_p_AllowIncompatiblePlatform=True_p_CommentOutSetVarDeclarations=True"
:setvar DefaultDataPath ""
:setvar DefaultLogPath ""

GO
:on error exit
```

**Previous Solution**

I previously did this using a .net build task in TFS.  This worked fine but want to do it in a powershell script now we have moved to DevOps
// Remove top section

```
Regex objRegex = new Regex(@"/\*\r\n:setvar(.*\r\n)*?(?=/\*)");
strFileContents = objRegex.Replace(strFileContents, "");
```

**My Attempts**

```
(Get-Content Upgrade.sql) -replace([Regex]::Escape(':setvar(.*\r\n)*?(?=/\*)'), '') | Set-Content Upgrade_Modified.sql
```

And

```
(Get-Content "Upgrade.sql") | ForEach-Object{$_ -replace [Regex]::Escape('(?m)^:setvar.*'), ''} | Set-Content "Upgrade_Output.sql"
```

Neither of which worked but I'm not very experienced with powershell or regex.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `-replace '^:setvar.*'` should work. `Escape` method is for escaping regex engine characters as literal strings. You do not want to do that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex string you are looking for here is `^:setvar.*`. The [Regex.Escape](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=netcore-3.1) method is used for escaping regex engine characters (`\`, `*`, `+`, `?`, `|`, `{`, `[`, `(`,`)`, `^`, `$`, `.`, `#`, and white space) as literal strings. You do not need it for this string.

```
(Get-Content "Upgrade.sql") -replace '^:setvar.*' | Set-Content Upgrade.sql
```

The inherent issue/benefit with `-replace` operator is the default replacement is an empty string. So you will be left with blank lines in your file if you don't replace newline characters. Without using regex single-line mode, `.` won't match any newline characters. If you want to remove entire lines, you will need to do something else in addition to just `-replace`. You may consider a different operator all together.

```
# for multi-line files as single strings return true/false only
(Get-Content "Upgrade.sql") -notmatch '^:setvar.*' | Set-Content Upgrade.sql

# for single or multi-line files
(Get-Content "Upgrade.sql") | Where {$_ -notmatch '^:setvar.*'} | Set-Content Upgrade.sql

# replacing newline characters
# -Raw switch reads in the file as a single string making newline characters replaceable.
# Now multi-line mode (?m) needs to be used to treat ^ as the beginning of each line
(Get-Content "Upgrade.sql" -Raw) -replace '(?m)^:setvar.*\r?\n' | Set-Content Upgrade.sql
```

`Get-Content` without the `-Raw` switch reads each line of the file as an array element. Therefore, your output of that array will add newline characters between each element regardless of the pre-output replacements.